# list all keyboard shortcuts currently assigned in Gimp

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, gimp

Is there a way to list all keyboard shortcuts currently assigned in Gimp (2.8.10) ?

Note that I'm not asking to be pointed to a website containing a list.

The reason for the question:

To make it easier to find out what keys are currently *not* assigned, so that the user can create their own short-cuts; it's frustrating guesswork otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Mac Os or Linux you can just view `~/.gimp-2.8/menurc` to see all your keybindings.

The following command produces a list of assigned keys without any extra text.

`awk -F\" '$4 != "" {print $4}' ~/.gimp-2.8/menurc`

The result on my machine is on http://pastebin.com/Fhh4kNu2.

Comment: Thanks @GCoda, this looks like what I'm after. I'd already looked in that file, but they keys are so buried in other text that I hadn't spotted them. I can improve the regexp. I will propose an edit for your answer.